# How can I keep reusing HBITMAP and HDC continually?

Tags: c++, sdl-2, gdi

I am trying to get HBIPMAP working by reusing the HBITMAP and the HDC for performance reasons.

This is a small test project I wanted to do to learn more about CPU based Rasterization.  For the window, im using SDL2.

The below code works if we comment out:

```
DeleteDC(hdcMem);
hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(device);
```

I can not find any example in the year 2018+.

mBackBuffer is just a Vector(DWORD)

```
void Device::createDeviceFromHWND(const HWND& hwnd, const int& width, const int& height)
{
    // This is hacked code for an example.

    auto device = GetDC(hwnd);
    DWORD colorSize = 4;    // ARGB;

    // Create page section
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/creating-named-shared-memory
    HANDLE hMapFile;
    LPCTSTR pBuf;
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga
    hMapFile = CreateFileMappingA
    (
        INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
        NULL,
        PAGE_READWRITE,
        0,
        width * height * colorSize,
        NULL
    );

    if (hMapFile == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    DWORD* buffer = (DWORD*)MapViewOfFile(
        hMapFile, 
        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 
        0, 
        0, 
        width * height * colorSize
    );

    BITMAPINFOHEADER header;
    memset(&header, 0, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/02f8ed65-8fed-4dda-9b94-7343a0cfa8c1
    header.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    header.biWidth = width;
    header.biHeight = height;
    header.biPlanes = 1;
    header.biBitCount = 32;
    header.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    header.biSizeImage = width * height * sizeof(BYTE);
    header.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    header.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    header.biClrUsed = 0;
    header.biClrImportant = 0;


    tagBITMAPINFO bitmap;
    memset(&bitmap, 0, sizeof(tagBITMAPINFO));
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-tagbitmapinfo
    tagRGBQUAD RGBQUAD;
    memset(&RGBQUAD, 0, sizeof(tagRGBQUAD));

    bitmap.bmiHeader = header;
    bitmap.bmiColors[0] = RGBQUAD;

    LPVOID p;
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdibsection
    auto hBitMap = CreateDIBSection
    (
        device,
        &bitmap,
        DIB_RGB_COLORS,
        &p,
        hMapFile,
        0
    );

    for (DWORD i = 0; i < width * height; ++i)
    {
        buffer[i] = 0xFF0000;
    }

    HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(device);
    auto oldHBITMAP = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitMap);

    BitBlt(
        device,
        0,
        0,
        width,
        height,
        hdcMem,
        0,
        0,
        SRCCOPY
    );

    DeleteDC(hdcMem);

    for (DWORD i = 0; i < width * height; ++i)
    {
        buffer[i] = 0;
    }

    hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(device);

    BitBlt(
        device,
        400,
        300,
        width,
        height,
        hdcMem,
        0,
        0,
        SRCCOPY
    );
}
```

The output is a red screen, but you should see the black section in corner right.

Comment: Is this C, or C++?  Tagging your question with the appropriate language will help it get better visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here, some not related to bitmap.

The handle from `GetDC` should be cleaned up by `ReleaseDC` when the handle is no longer needed.

The handle from `CreateFileMapping` should be cleaned up by `CloseHandle`, and `MapViewOfFile` should be cleaned up by `UnmapViewOfFile`.

`HBITMAP` handle must be cleaned up by `DeleteObject`

It is recommend to cleanup after `SelectObject` by calling `SelectOject(hMemDC, oldHBitmap)`

If you don't restore the old bitmap, and try to delete `hMemDC`, Windows cannot fulfill the request because there is another bitmap selected in device context. Windows will try to fix this error but it may fail if the code is too convoluted.

Note that Windows gives you a limit of 10,000 GDI handles. The application will crash very quickly if you don't manage these handles properly. Refer to WinAPI documentation for these functions. If in doubt, use the task manager to monitor "GDI handles" for your program.

The code should work as expected once you fix these problems, see the example below.

This of course is for demonstration only. In real world application you probably want to save the `HBITMAP` in the heap, instead of stack, as well as some other values. You want to minimize repeated creating these handles.

As noted in other answers and comments, painting should be done in response to `WM_PAINT`, where you get `HDC` from `BeginPaint` (and cleanup with `EndPaint`). Therefore you should avoid `GetDC`/`ReleaseDC`

```
void Device::createDeviceFromHWND(const HWND& hwnd, const int& width, const int& height)
{
    auto hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    auto hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0,
        width * height * sizeof(DWORD), NULL);

    auto buffer = (DWORD*)MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 
        width * height * sizeof(DWORD));

    BITMAPINFOHEADER biheader = { sizeof(biheader), width, height, 1, 32, BI_RGB };

    LPVOID bits;
    auto hbitmap = CreateDIBSection(hdc, (BITMAPINFO*)&biheader, DIB_RGB_COLORS,
        &bits, hMapFile, 0);

    for(int i = 0; i < width * height; ++i)
        buffer[i] = 0xFF0000;

    auto memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    auto oldhbitmap = SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);

    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, width, height, memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    for(int i = 0; i < width * height; ++i)
        buffer[i] = 0;
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 100, 100, memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    SelectObject(memdc, oldhbitmap); //<- ***EDIT***
    //oldhbitmap is selected in to memdc, now we can destroy hbitmap and memdc

    DeleteObject(hbitmap);
    DeleteDC(memdc);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
    UnmapViewOfFile(buffer);
    CloseHandle(hMapFile);
}
```

Side note, you don't gain anything by using reference operator `&` for constant values. Just change the function prototype as follows:

```
void createDeviceFromHWND(const HWND hwnd, const int width, const int height);
```

---

Also, this can be done without `CreateFileMapping`, and use `buffer` shown below. `buffer` will be valid as long as `hbitmap` is valid.

```
void test(const HWND hwnd, const int w, const int h)
{
    auto hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

    //use the negative value of height, so bitmap bits are not upside-down
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi = { sizeof(bi), w, -h, 1, 32, BI_RGB };

    DWORD* buffer;
    auto hbitmap = CreateDIBSection(hdc, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS,
        (void**)&buffer, NULL, 0);

    auto memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    auto oldbmp = SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);

    for(int i = 0; i < w * h; ++i) buffer[i] = 0xFF0000;
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, w, h, memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    //draw black square on top-left
    for(int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
        for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
            buffer[y * w + x] = 0;
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 100, 100, memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    //cleanup:
    SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);
    DeleteObject(hbitmap); //<- buffer is not valid after hbitmap is destroyed
    DeleteDC(memdc);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Also, did not know about the const and reference.  Is there any reason why I have to do all of this with WM_PAINT?  I can 100% guarantee I will not be using WM_PAINT for anything in my project.

Comment: I had an error for `SelectObject`, please see `***EDIT***`. In plain Windows programming, painting should be done in response to `WM_PAINT`. SDL handles `WM_PAINT` itself, so maybe your code is okay. `GetDC(hwnd)` still seems wrong. By the way, I should have added, reference operator is useful is some cases, for example in `foo(const std::string &large_text)`, it prevents making a copy. I meant you don't need it for built-in types like `int`.

Comment: I tried returning "buffer" from you last example from inside the function after deleting the "hBitmap" and it worked just fine for reading the pixels data. Am I leaking memory here? If I try to free the "buffer", I get an access violation error.

Comment: @victor `buffer` is owned by `CreateDIBSection`, see documentation. We don't delete it directly, we call `DeleteObject(hbitmap)`. You should not delete `hbitmap` if you still need `buffer`

Comment: I looked everywhere on msdn, and didn't find anything about the buffer until your answer. It states a few things about synchronicity and GdiFlush, but I'm taking a screenshot from another window and nothing else accesses the handle created by CreateDIBSection but a this single function, so it doesn't really matter to me. I think what I'm doing is equivalent of keeping a pointer that's been freed: the data is there, but it's not mine and anything could happen to it.

Comment: Guess I shouldn't keep the HBITMAP either if I'm deleting the HDC?

Comment: First, this is a ridculously thorough answer.  Thank you!!!  Next: Above, the first code sample uses a combination of `CreateFileMapping`, `MapViewOfFile`, and `CreateDIBSection`.  Here is a double buffering example that uses `CreateCompatibleDC` and `CreateCompatibleBitmap`: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/617212/Custom-Controls-in-Win-API-The-Painting  Is there any dis/advantages to either technique?

Comment: @kevinarpe `CreateFileMapping` etc. is generally used to share memory with another process. I assume that's why the asker included it. Don't use it if you don't need that memory sharing. It just slows things down. Use the example you have linked to.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is wrong. When the target window gets WM_PAINT all your work will be undone.

Always paint your windows the way you want them with WM_PAINT and BeginPaint.

Comment: Also, there's no need to explicitly create an `HBITMAP` for each paint - you can use straight `StretchDIBits` if your data to paint is in your bytes buffer.

Comment: I did not know this would snowball on me.  Sorry.  I am actually using SDL2 creating the window.  This is a project to do some CPU based Rasterization.

Comment: @user954753: I added the tag for you. I don't think I'll be of any more help. While this answer is "right" it kinda needs to go away once an answer that actually uses the library comes along.

Comment: Okay thank you.  I am actually trying to get something working with Matteo Italia  suggestion -- but its proving troublesome ^^.

Answer (score 0):

You are not editing the bitmap here:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < width * height; ++i)
{
    mBackBuffer[i] = 0;
}
```

just filling the array, the bitmap was created from, with nulls.

Comment: Okay.  Yes.  So then how can I directly edit the HBITMAP with the mBackBuffer?  Do I really need to create an HBITMAP each time?  mBackBuffer is just a Vector<DWORD>

Comment: Just use GetObject (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getobject) call to get BITMAP structure using HBITMAP you have and edit bmBits inside.

Comment: You can create a page of shared memory, and create a DIBSection over it. Then you can map it in memory and use it both through GDI and modifying the raw pixels. But if all you want is to blit some pixel data, just use `StretchDIBits`

Comment: @MatteoItalia I would like to get what you mentioned, sounds more like a rendering pipeline where I would just need to edit the raw pixels and bitblt it to the device.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I have a version working as you suggested.  Do I have to DeleteDC each time after bitblting?

Comment: @user954753: it depends from how you obtained the DC. A DC obtained through `CreateDC` or `CreateCompatibleDC` needs `DeleteDC`; a DC obtained through `GetDC` needs a `ReleaseDC`; a DC obtained through a `BeginPaint` needs an `EndPaint`. But in general, if you do `GetDC` or `CreateDC` you are doing something fishy; they have their use, but generally your "regular" paint cycle should go through `WM_PAINT` and thus `BeginPaint`/`EndPaint`.

Comment: When I delete the DC(hdcMem), and then remake the hdcMem(before bitclting again), the second BitBlt does not work, but if I dont delete the DC, it will work. I just update the question now.

Comment: You have hBitMap selected on the old hdcMem instance, probably need to select again